# Command not found after installing pry

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv, pry

I installed pry and related gems using the following line in a bash prompt:

```
gem install pry-plus --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Successful gem installation was reported from that command.

All the instructions I've found say that after installing pry I can get to a pry prompt by entering `pry` as a bash command. However, the actual result is `bash: pry: command not found`

`which pry` reports `no pry in (...)` where the ellipses are $PATH. In contrast, `which rake` reports `/local/tbh/rbenv/shims/rake` and `which gem` reports `/local/tbh/rbenv/shims/gem`

Why did the command for pry not get created by gem install? How can I get it to work as designed?

(I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 with rbenv (not RVM) under Scientific Linux as a virtual environment.)

Comment: Try `rbenv rehash` to refresh your shims.

Comment: Executing `rbenv rehash` did indeed make the `pry` command work as advertized. Thanks!

Comment: Great, I've posted it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

rbenv caches current Ruby executables as so-called *shims*. You have to run

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

after installing a new executable in order to [refresh the shims](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-rehash).