# zsh command not found: zeus, mailcatcher, etc?

Tags: shell, path, rubygems, zsh, zeus

I've been going over this for awhile now and can't seem to get it permanently resolved. Was hoping someone could clarify for me.

I'm pretty familiar with setting up my PATH and working with ZSH. I have a ton of custom helpers, plugins, etc. going on nicely.

But for some reason, when I do `gem install gemname` and attempt to use it globally, it occassionally says `gem not found.` I found this happening recently with `zeus`:

```
tmtm|master⚡ ⇒ gem which zeus
/Users/andrewmartin/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb

tmtm|master⚡ ⇒ zeus
zsh: correct 'zeus' to '_zeus' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: zeus
```

I had the same problem recently with `mailcatcher` and was never really able to get it installed or working. I had a couple really good Rails buddies take a look, they were confused as well.

Here's my PATH:

```
tmtm|master⚡ ⇒ echo $PATH
/Users/andrewmartin/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin/npm:/Users/andrewmartin/.rbenv/shims:/Users/andrewmartin/.rbenv/:/Users/andrewmartin/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/Users/andrewmartin/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/andrewmartin/Dropbox/Favorites/dotfiles/bin
```

Any idea why some of these common, global gems are simply not found in the zsh shell? Happy to share any other information that would make this helpful. I am using `rbenv`.

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out!

Simple!

Whenever you install a new gem with rbenv, you have to use the `rbenv rehash` command. It said it found one, so I just deleted the one that existed, then typed it again. When I opened a new terminal, both `mailcatcher` and `zeus` were magically available to me.

Awesome! Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327416/command-not-found-after-installing-pry) by the way.